# Graphql filters for json files in gatsby js

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, frontend, gatsby

I am very new in Web development. 
I am using 'gatsby-transformer-json' plugin.
I have 2 json files in my directory. ie. a.json, b.json. 
I can filter according to the contents inside the files.
My question is, is it possible to filter based on file name?

in my case, for example : *"give me the content when jsonFileName ='a'"*

Thank you.

BR

Comment: The best way to explore this is to play around in the GraphiQL editor that Gatsby spins up on develop at `localhost:8000/___graphql`. If you use `filter` on a query it will suggest all the fields you can filter by. Useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can filter by a bunch of parameters, including `pathname` (`relative` and `absolute`). In your case:

```
query {
  allFile(filter: {
    relativePath: { eq: "a.json" }
  }) {
    edges {
      node { 
        id
        anyValue
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

It's a bit generic question and without knowing where do you want to use it it's difficult to guess how the result code will loke like. For example, you can use your query as a page generator, in that case, you can call `createPages` method depending on that query result.